# Need to write a admin module in joomla for managing the contents from front end

Tags: forms, joomla, module, admin, joomla1.6

I am very new to Joomla , i want to write a module for Joomla admin to create a form to add name, title and file upload in the admin side and also i want to manage the list of contents in the list as that of Joomla default behavior. Its quiet easy in Drupal like creating content type and data entered using content tyle can be moderated using views. like thats is there any free modules available in joomla.

For the front end we are providing the data through web services so we no need to worry abut the front end. only cms end with form and records moderations. Please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of extensions that allow you to do this already.  They're all listed on the JED, under [Forms Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms).